# How add notifications in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

how to add notification with action buttons in pwa of react js give some idea i am new to react js

I am trying to add notifications in my progressive web app using react js but it simply gives toast message it does not gives notification behavior just like mobile application gives.

Comment: To enable push notifications and offline access in general, PWA uses Service Worker. It is a JavaScript file that runs separately from the main browser thread and lets the application control network requests, cache them and access acquired content

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `react-notifications` library for adding notifications to your web app. Here is the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-notifications) for the documentation and the npm package.
Here is some example code for checking the notifcations.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  NotificationContainer,
  NotificationManager,
} from 'react-notifications';
    
    class Notifications extends React.Component {
      createNotification = (type) => {
        return () => {
          switch (type) {
            case 'info':
              NotificationManager.info('Info message');
              break;
            case 'success':
              NotificationManager.success('Success message', 'Title here');
              break;
            case 'warning':
              NotificationManager.warning(
                'Warning message',
                'Close after 3000ms',
                3000
              );
              break;
            case 'error':
              NotificationManager.error('Error message', 'Click me!', 5000, () => {
                alert('callback');
              });
              break;
          }
        };
      };
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button
              className="btn btn-info"
              onClick={this.createNotification('info')}
            >
              Info
            </button>
            <hr />
            <button
              className="btn btn-success"
              onClick={this.createNotification('success')}
            >
              Success
            </button>
            <hr />
            <button
              className="btn btn-warning"
              onClick={this.createNotification('warning')}
            >
              Warning
            </button>
            <hr />
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={this.createNotification('error')}
            >
              Error
            </button>
    
            <NotificationContainer />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default Notifications;
```